# is it possible to set per-file options for Nedit like you can do for emacs/vim

Tags: vim, emacs

With VIM or Emacs I can put comments in the file that will be VIM's settings for that file:

```
/*
 * Local Variables:     
 * mode: C
 * c-basic-offset: 4
 * c-indentation-style: linux
 * indent-tabs-mode: nil
 * default-tab-width: 8
 * fill-column: 125
 * End:
 *
 * vim: et:sw=4:ts=8:si:cindent:cino=\:0,g0,(0:
 */
```

Can the same be done with Nedit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, sadly, no.

The longer answer is (as I'm sure you're aware) yes if you wrap the call to nedit in a shell script. The script would need to look at the head of the file you're trying to open for information concerning settings. You could then spit this information out to a file and use the "--import" option to load those settings into nedit.

Hope this helps a little.

Rob

Comment: dunno, it looks a bit stagnant doesn't it? Still a damn good text editor though.